# Run Boxstarter in "Debug" mode?

Tags: powershell, boxstarter

I'm writing some BoxStarter scripts for unattended installation.

I've put some `Write-Debug` in my scripts and would like to conditionally see their output.
Is there a flag I could run BoxStarter with (`BoxStarter.bat PackageName -Debug` don't works)?

Same debugging idea: Is there a way to make BoxStarter/Powershell tell at which file and line it found the fatal error that makes it stop? I know BoxStarter packages get packed into a *.nupkg* file but maybe is there a way to retrieve original file and line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you use `write-debug` then the output will appear in c:\chocolatey\chocolateyinstall\chocolateyinstall.log
2. To get good stacktrace info, I suggest wrapping the contents of your package in a try catch and in your catch block have it include:

`Write-ChocolateyFailure 'MyPackage' $($_.Exception.ToString())`

Comment: Fixed command (cannot edit answer: fix is too short): `Write-ChocolateyFailure 'MyPackage' $($_.Exception.ToString())` Gives more info indeed.